# Restart computer over the Internet via command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, remote-access

Is it possible to restart a computer over the internet via command prompt?

I know you can restart/shutdown in network using:

```
shutdown /m \\mycomputer /r /t 0
```

I have been able to use this in conjunction with VPN to restart my computer. But I was wondering if there was a way to use the IP address and perhaps an open port to send the command to the remote computer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is enable the telnet server on your target machine.  Windows server 2000 and newer has it, as well as Windows 7 and Vista.

Then forward port 23 (telnet) from your router to your target machine's internal IP.

You would then be able to telnet to the public IP of your router and get a command prompt on your internal machine.

Comment: Given that telnet is one of the frequently-scanned ports, you should consider forwarding a different, high number port such as 6901 to port 23 on your network. When you telnet in, you just need to specify the port and you're away, but it will make things much harder for Internet Bad Guys.

Comment: or better yet, use ssh, [winrm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx) , [rsh](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rsh.mspx?mfr=true) or the remote access capabilities of powershell

Answer (score 2):

Shutter can do this. [Shutter - Den4B Products](http://www.den4b.com/?x=products)

You need to have an open port on your firewall to allow communications with the Shutter service. It's password protected so you don't get just anyone scanning and rebooting your computer on a hoot.

Access through your web browser, choose the operation and execute.

Answer (score 1):

Technically - yes, you can do this. The UNC syntax accepts IPv4 addresses, and you only have to open port 445 for this to work.

Practically? I'm not even sure which is worse, exposing the ever-secure SMB service to the entire Internet versus enabling plain-text Telnet as others suggest – both sound equally bad to me. (AFAIK, Windows Telnet cannot use separate credentials for NTLM, which makes it less secure than SMB on public machines. On the other hand, it's got less security holes so far than Windows SMB.)