# Remote restart computer using command line

Tags: windows-7, remote, reboot

I want to remote restart a computer with the administrator account user and password provided.

1. Can this be done from command line ?
   like so : *shutdown \m pcName \r*
2. If not can you please provide a way which was tested.

I've tried : [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921905/wmi-to-reboot-remote-machine) and [solution2](https://superuser.com/questions/361960/restart-computer-over-the-internet-via-command-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [Sysinternals psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

```
psexec \\targethost cmd
```

will open a command prompt to the remote system. 
then just issue a shutdown command like 'shutdown \m'

Here is the syntax guide for psexec: http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html