# Gentle Restart or Shutdown from win10 lockscreen on startup

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, window, lock-screen

I have recently noticed while booting up my PC sometimes it has said no display signal (I have 2 monitors and I can't seem to get any connection from them when it does this) and simply pressing the power button does not work and I figure holding it down is a bad idea. I have no way of knowing if it even made it to the Win10 lockscreen but I'm assuming it does, so is there an easy way to do this? Because if not, there certainly should be

Comment: Try shutting down with both monitors on (not on monitor power save). Then do an orderly shutdown from the start button.  Does this provide a better startup?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained better in my post, no matter if I try to turn them on they will always go back into power saver mode so I can't view what's going on

Comment: Thanks. Any monitor that can go into power save has a Monitor (not Windows) setting to prevent that. Look in your Monitor documentation and disable Power Save. That should work.

Comment: Thank you, I just had a look and disabled monitor sleep for both my monitors (hopefully that's what you mean). I will report back here if I have the issue again when booting up, thank you :)

Comment: Please let me know because I have answered your question.

Comment: Op, Windows doesn't really have a gentle emergency shutdown (like linux's magic sysreq reisub), but if you have another PC on the same network, you may be able to perform a remote shutdown using psexec or remote desktop sessions. https://superuser.com/questions/514585/remote-restart-computer-using-command-line/514588#514588

Comment: "Windows doesn't really have a gentle emergency shutdown"  - it may be a matter of language, but Start, Shutdown is an orderly shutdown that will shut down a monitor not set for power save and start it back up again properly.